# Emacs won't start slime: MAKE-AUTO-FLUSH-THREAD is undefined

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, slime

After loading `emacs25 -nw` (or just `emacs`, doesn't matter) and telling him to start slime (<kbd>M-x slime</kbd>), this is what i get.

```
The function SWANK/BACKEND::MAKE-AUTO-FLUSH-THREAD is undefined.
   [Condition of type UNDEFINED-FUNCTION]

Restarts:
 0: [CONTINUE] Retry calling SWANK/BACKEND::MAKE-AUTO-FLUSH-THREAD.
 1: [USE-VALUE] Call specified function.
 2: [RETURN-VALUE] Return specified values.
 3: [RETURN-NOTHING] Return zero values.
 4: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 5: [ABORT] abort thread (#<THREAD "worker" RUNNING {1006CCF143}>)

Backtrace:
  0: ("undefined function" #<SWANK/GRAY::SLIME-OUTPUT-STREAM 
{10072A4F33}>)
 --more--
```

However, if I the just press 3, it seems to work out and start what I want. I'd like to know what's going on tho, since it is a good idea in general.

Comment: which program runs lisp on your computer?

Comment: and what system...?

Comment: @manandearth it's Debian. And sbcl, I think

Comment: Maybe you can describe how you tried to install everything ? FYI here is an up to date and collaborative doc: [getting started](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/getting-started.html). Also there are ready-to-use editors if you want to write some CL before you fix that: [editors support](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/editor-support.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `sbcl` I find the following configuration works for me:

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "/usr/bin/sbcl")
(load (expand-file-name "~/quicklisp/slime-helper.el"))
```

you wil need to install quicklisp and set sbcl as inferior-lisp.
follow [Astray_BI's Blog](https://astraybi.wordpress.com/2015/08/02/how-to-install-slimesbclquicklisp-into-emacs/)

Comment: Doesn't help. I don't know, I didn't even have this ~/.emacs file, only emacs.d dir. I created it, and added that what he said but it didn't help(

Comment: 2 cents: SBCL is in Debian, so `apt install sbcl` works. ([Cookbook: getting started](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/getting-started.html)). Also `~/.emacs` and `~/.emacs.d/init.el` are equivalent (so I prefer init.el to put it under version control more easily).

Comment: ~/.emacs.d/
auto-save-list/   elpa/ 

This is what I have in there.

Comment: so much of the functionality comes from configuring your init.el file in emacs. create a simple setup file such as instructed [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-Examples.html) or look for some basic configuration posted online, copy it to an emacs buffer and save it as init.el in the .emacs.d directory.